# converter-sample.c contains duplicate main

Tags: cocoa, xcode, asn.1, mac-app-store

I'm trying to deploy an application on the mac app store.

I'm working through the process of adding the code to validate the recipts

In accordance to the [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/devcenter/mac/documents/validating.html) I've compleated the follwing steps

1. Installed asn1c using `sudo port install asn1c`
2. Created a file `modlule.asn1` in a directory `asn1c_dir` from listing 1-1.
3. `cd asn1c_dir`
4. `asn1c -fnative-types module.asn1`
5. Then in Xcode "add existing files" and add the `asn1c_dir` directory
6. Try building, but I get ~900 errors
7. In the target build settings, I check the box next to "Always Search User Paths"

I now get a single error saying "Duplicate symbol _main in /foo/bar/ppc/converter-sample.o and /foo/bar/ppc/main.o

I've tracked this to the fact that it looks like the file converter-sample.c declares it's own `int main()` function which is bad right?

any help would be appreciated.

Comment: have you tried commenting out the main() function in converter-sample.c?

Comment: Yup, that worked. Turns out you don't need the converter-sample.c file in the project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So for metric reasons, I'll answer this question.

`converter-sample.c` is an **unnecessary** file. **Delete it**. Go about your life a happy person.